# Perl hash argument in use Module

Tags: perl, arguments, perl-module

Some Perl modules are imported with hash argument, like:

```
use Test::Simple tests => 1
```

which is not consistent with documented `use` usage variants:

> ```
> use Module VERSION LIST
> use Module VERSION
> use Module LIST
> use Module
> use VERSION
> ```
>
> Imports some semantics into the current package from the named module, generally by aliasing certain subroutine or variable names into your package.

while in our case, we are using hash instead of list, at least semantically - of course,

```
use Test::Simple qw(tests 1)
```

is equivalent, but makes no sense for the human outsider, who is expecting the list to be a list of names to import.

How do you explain/defend this deviation? Is it the recommended syntactic sugar to allow a module to be imported with parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should reread the documentation you quoted.

*Imports some **semantics** into the current package from the named module, generally by aliasing certain subroutine or variable names into your package.*

It's not just for importing a list of subs.

---

> How do you explain/defend this deviation?

You mentioned three deviations.

1. The belief that `=>` indicates a hash.

   This stems from the misconception that there's such a thing as a hash initializer. Explain that Perl doesn't have initializers, that `=` denotes an ordinary assignment even when the LHS of it is `%hash` or `my %hash`. Hashes and arrays are types of variables, not data.
2. The belief that the list passed to `use Test::Simple` is a list of symbols to import.

   I'm not sure how that's a problem. You can refer them to Test::Simple's documentation if it is.
3. The belief that the list passed to `use MODULE` is a list of symbols to import.

   There are plenty of counter examples, including commonly used core modules strict, warnings, CGI, CGI::Carp and Test::More.

None of the deviations should be defended. These aren't useful metaphors.

Comment: worth emphasizing whenever the confusion in 1. arises: "hash" and "array" are *variable* types, not *data* types.  and there is no variable here.

Answer (score 6):

[perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)

> The => operator is a synonym for the comma except that it causes a
> word on its left to be interpreted as a string if it begins with a
> letter or underscore and is composed only of letters, digits and
> underscores. This includes operands that might otherwise be
> interpreted as operators, constants, single number v-strings or
> function calls. If in doubt about this behavior, the left operand can
> be quoted explicitly.
>
> Otherwise, the => operator behaves exactly as the comma operator or
> list argument separator, according to context.

So it's `use Module LIST` syntax

Comment: it should be obvious from the question text that the questioner knows that, and the question is higher-level..

Comment: @mykhal, if you know it, I don't understand what is the question. `tests => 1` = `'test', 1` = `qw(test 1)`.

Comment: Suic: would you import an integer literal from a module?

Comment: it's just equivalent to `require Module; Module->import( 'test', 1 );` You are free fo define any `import` sub. it can even do no import at all

Answer (score 3):

As you have stated, this falls under the `use Module LIST` category.

I think the key to understanding how to interpret the use for `LIST` is to realize that `use Module LIST;` translates to the following line:

```
BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }
```

The module *appears* to treat the `LIST` as elements to populate a hash because the relevant package has a custom `import` subroutine:

```
sub import {
    my($class) = shift;

    # Don't run all this when loading ourself.
    return 1 if $class eq 'Test::Builder::Module';

    my $test = $class->builder;

    my $caller = caller;

    $test->exported_to($caller);

    $class->import_extra( \@_ );
    my(@imports) = $class->_strip_imports( \@_ );

    $test->plan(@_);

    $class->export_to_level( 1, $class, @imports );
}
```

---

`Test::More` also utilizes this "pattern".

Comment: the question is yet higher-level (i'd say philosophical). focus on "Imports some semantics into the current package from the named module, generally by aliasing certain subroutine or variable names into your package."

Answer (score 2):

ikegami does an excellent job answering "How do you explain/defend this deviation?" (that is, there *is* no deviation here).

To answer: "Is it the recommended syntactic sugar to allow a module to be imported with parameters?"

No, a general purpose module should usually avoid doing this, at least for configuration settings, because it encourages a design of global variables in the module controlling functionality.  And that means two independent other modules cannot use the module in question with different configuration.  An example of this misuse is Math::BigInt (and friends).

The Test modules are a special case; they are only likely to be used by a main script (or as a superclass of a module used in a main script), so my objection doesn't apply.

(Certainly a module could go to the trouble of making whatever is passed to import have pragma-like lexical scope or be bound to a particular calling package, but those two options are slightly different in effect and you create the possibility of erroneous expectations in the cases where they differ, as well as making it difficult for the same caller to use multiple configurations.)

In almost every case, it would be far better to support an OO interface and have such settings be instance attributes.

Answer (score -1):

Using this form `use Test::Simple tests => 1` is normal way for Perl as the symbol `=>` is the same as comma operator `,`. So it is not syntactic sugar that's just another way to do something. TIMTOWTDI